# Save the color with the help of color jquery or any other method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want save the css in css file, changes done by jquery?
eg. i want to change the background color with CSS method and save that background color for all time.

If anybody having a another way to do this. please share.
Basically i want to do this that if Dominos login in my portal then his dashboard come in blue background and MacD login then dashboard open in yellow background like this for all. All should be in same file

Comment: you can save in cookie and read from there or you should you ajax and database i think

Comment: I think the better way to do this is to store personal settings in DB and then change this view depends on user login
edit: 
Furthermore your way of thinking is very very bad in this situation and you cannot do this like you want to. You cannot edit file everytime user log in and change the background color in css File . Thats insane
Another way is if you have separeted css files for every single user ... which is also stupid solution.
The best way is to store it in DB

Comment: first of all, you can't save the run time color change directly into the CSS file. But if wish to do that, why don't you toggle class according to the User,   write a specific query, so that it will identify the user and according to that toggle the class with specific background color.

Comment: Its best to use localstorage and store preferences that way http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage and save users data on the client.

Local storage works as key/pair: [W3-Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

**Save data to local storage:**

```
localStorage.backgroundcolor = $("your element").css('background');
```

**Get data from local storage and use it when user is logged on:**

```
$("your element).css('background', localStorage.backgroundcolor)
```